# Representing infinite paths from one point to other using parameterization

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus

Below the picture is from the standard Goldstein textbook of Classical Mechanics. In Hamilton's principle part, there is an equation that represents the set of all possible paths from $x1$ to $x2$ (as I have understood it and please tell me if I am getting something wrong here). We do it by setting the two parameters $η(x)$ and $α$. I can see how $α$ can be used to amplify the additional variation function to add variations in the correct path but η(x) although at the time of selection can be arbitrary but after doing so it is just a function of $x$ which can just be amplified using α. Then how can we say that $y(x,α)$ is the family of all possible curves from $x1$ to $x2$?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, $y(x,\alpha)$ is not the family of *all* possible curves from $x_1$ to $x_2$. Indeed Goldstein doesn't claim that it is. He just writes that *a possible set* of varied paths is given by $y(x, \alpha)$.